# Force NetBeans to provide code completion for a JavaScript variable assuming a specific type

Tags: javascript, netbeans, ide, code-completion

I am using NetBeans, specifically the HTML5 & PHP bundle. Currently I'm working on a game which makes use of the HTML5 canvas element. I have a global variable called `context`:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Obviously, the IDE has no idea what type `context` is, since it cannot find out the type of `canvas` in the first place and it can't possibly know what `getContext()` is going to return when called on that `canvas`. I would like NetBeans to provide code completion feature for `context` assuming it represents a specific type (namely, `CanvasRenderingContext2D`). After doing some research I found this: https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/defining_variable_type_in_a. The site states that such feature can be used in PHP by providing a PHPDoc comment which looks like the following: `/* @var $variable type */`. I am aware it concerns PHP, but I decided to give it a try in JavaScript as well:

```
/* @var context CanvasRenderingContext2D */
```

Unfortunately, the above did not work. I thought that maybe NetBeans for some reason doesn't know that type and tried something simpler:

```
/* @var test HTMLImageElement */
```

Again, there were no proposals for `test` except for the ones that are native to all JavaScript objects.

So, is this even possible? I would appreciate it if someone provided a solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript uses JSDoc, not PHPDoc, so you need to use

```
/** @type HTMLImageElement */
var myImage;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine with `HTMLImageElement`, unfortunately there are no hints for `CanvasRenderingContext2D`. It seems they haven't added support for that yet: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=234149 but anyway this is the right answer to my question, so I'm accepting it.